# How to pass to a function a dictionary whose values are lists

Tags: python, function, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of parameters such as this:

```
import numpy as np

param1 = np.arange(0., 1., 0.01)
param2 = np.arange(10., 8000., 100.)
...
```

I also have a function `foo` defined with a list of keyword arguments `arg1, arg2, ...` and their default values:

`def foo(arg1=default1, arg2=default2, ...)`

What I need to do is call this function, changing one of those default values (one by one) with the arguments and values from my list of parameters like so:

```
foo(arg1=param1[0])
foo(arg1=param1[1])
...
foo(arg2=param2[0])
foo(arg2=param2[0])
```

The best way that I thought of was to create a dictionary of all parameters, and then iterate over keys and values and create a new temporary dictionary out of it and then call the function:

```
all_params = {'arg1':param1, 'arg2':param2, ...}
for key, value_list in all_params.items():
    for value in value_list:
        tmp_dict = {key:value}
        foo(**tmp_dict)
```

But I have a feeling that 1) I'm iterating in a non-Pythonic way, 2) and that there is obviously a much better way to solve this problem.

EDIT: streamlined the nested loops a bit according to @Sebastian's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) I'm iterating in a non-Pythonic way

"Pythonic" is subjective.

> 2) That there is obviously a much better way to solve this
>   problem.

Not so, what you're currently doing is the only possible scenario considering you've to pass them by keyword and that you've to pass them one at a time.

---

As an improvement you might consider passing all your arguments at the same time.

MVCE:

First, define your function and dictionary:

```
In [687]: def foo(a, b, c):
     ...:     print(a, b, c)
     ...:  

In [688]: dict_ = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5, 6], 'c' : [7, 8, 9]}
```

Convert to dict of iters:

```
In [689]: dict_ = {k : iter(v) for k, v in dict_.items()}
```

Run your loop:

```
In [690]: while True:
     ...:     try: 
     ...:         foo(**{k : next(v) for k, v in dict_.items()})
     ...:     except StopIteration: 
     ...:         break
     ...:     
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: This is very useful! Apart from it being almost exactly what I need, I also learned now something new about iterators and how they work (I'm not very experienced in Python).

One question though: I need to pass only a single key:value combination to my function at a time, not all key:value combinations in the dictionary. So first I'd go over all the values of key 'a' and use default values for 'b' and 'c', then switch to 'b', and so on. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @MarkoF In trying to fix your problem I notice you've done the exact same thing. Ergo, your existing solution is already good.

Comment: @MarkoF And one more thing. Remember, pythonic is subjective. :-)

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know that I've not completely wasted hour and a half trying to get to this solution. :-) I've also tried to implement this using list comprehension, but just got lost in it and gave up, returning to good old nested loops. Still, your iterator approach is really useful, I'll remember it.

Comment: @MarkoF It's good when you have to pass in multiple arguments from separate lists together. However, when passing 1 arg at a time, it doesn't make much sense, which is why I reiterate that what you've going going on is pretty good. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple in my opinion.

```
def foo(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    return a * b + c

args1 = [1, 2]
args2 = [3, 4, 5]
args3 = [6, 7]

args = [args1, args2, args3]

d = {}
for n, a in enumerate(args):  # Enumerate through all of the parameters.
    for val in a:  # For each parameter, iterate through all of the desired arguments.
        a = [0, 0, 0]  # default_args
        a[n] = val  # Insert the relavent argument into the correct parameter location.
        d[tuple(a)] = foo(*a)  # Call the function and unpack all of the arguments.

# This dictionary holds the function arguments as keys the returned values for those arguments.
>>> d
{(0, 0, 6): 6,
 (0, 0, 7): 7,
 (0, 3, 0): 0,
 (0, 4, 0): 0,
 (0, 5, 0): 0,
 (1, 0, 0): 0,
 (2, 0, 0): 0}
```

Comment: The OP clearly states that he wants to change one keyword argument per call

Comment: I'll undownvote but still believe is a bad answer a) The OP never mentioned that he needs to  have access to the result b) The solution is no more elegant than the OP's solution c) With the `deepcopy` it's certainly not more efficient d) It isn't justified why we must force ourselves to use positional arguments e) You should have created a new answer since you got an upvote for a wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the iterating slightly, so that you don't need to access `all_params[key]` again, like this:

```
for key, param in all_params.items():
    for value in param:
```